# How to send value if only the current button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a list of forms (list of hotels).
Every form has one value (id of hotel), and a submit button.

All the buttons send to the same page.

I want to get using session the value of id hotel from only **the clicked  button submit**

I tried using session and post but all gave me an error.
Here is the first page:

```
            foreach ($response->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary as $hotel){
<form action="details.php" method="POST">
                                    <?php    
$_SESSION["id"]=$hotel->hotelId;
echo $_SESSION["id"];?>  

                                     <button class="bookbtn mt1"  name=<?php echo $_SESSION["id"] ?>type="submit">Voir Détails</button>
```

The second page that had to receive the value from clicked button:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
  $url  ='http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?minorRev=28';
  $url .= '&apiKey=pg43dnudzv89cvuf2n5bfqce';
  $url .= '&cid=55509';
  $url .= '&hotelId='.$_SESSION["id"].'&locale=fr_FR-French';
```

When I display session it shows the hotel id different from the id I get from the clicked button.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about `event.target.name`  ?

Comment: if  you  talk  about  jq  or  javascript  i  do  not  know  about  them please  if  you  have  solution  to  this  issue  tel  me  what  to  do  exatly

Comment: Why are you doing it like that? Is that any special reason not to use a single form with a list of hotels elements inside it and just post the ID of the selected hotel to that second page?

Comment: because  the  number  of  hotel  is  inknowen ! ,20,30,50  etc !

Comment: form has no `input` elements...what do you expect? Suggest you study some form tutorials. Not to mention you overwrite the session variable every iteration of your loop. None of this code makes any sense whatsoever

Comment: maybe  i  have  incorrect  code  so  how  to  detet  who  is  the  button  clicked ?..you  have  to  know  we  have  indefine  number  of  button !

Comment: it  was  so  easy !  if  button  clicked  then  set  session  by  avalue  current  and  send  it  the  another  page  !  thas  all  what  i  want  to  know  !!

Answer (score 2):

make button like this

```
<?php 
foreach ($response->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary as $hotel)
{  
$_SESSION["id"]=$hotel->hotelId;
echo $_SESSION["id"];?>
?>
<input class="bookbtn mt1"  name='<?php echo $hotel->hotelId;?>' id='btn_<?php echo $hotel->hotelId; ?> onclick="send(<?php echo $hotel->hotelId; ?>)" type="button" value="Voir Détails">
<?php } ?>
<script>
function send(id)
{
$.ajax({
  url: "details.php",
  type: 'post',
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data: '{id:id}',
  success: function (data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
     }
  });
}
</script>
```